# Output the VAR name and its VALUE

Tags: variables, symbols, format

I defined these variables/functions:

```el
(defvar FirstVar-p nil
  "DOCSTRING")

(defun toggle-first-var ()
  "DOCSTRING"
  (interactive)
  (setq FirstVar-p (not FirstVar-p)))


(defvar SecondVar-p nil
  "DOCSTRING")

(defun toggle-second-var ()
  "DOCSTRING"
  (interactive)
  (setq SecondVar-p (not SecondVar-p)))


(defvar ThirdVar-p nil
  "DOCSTRING")

(defun toggle-third-var ()
  "DOCSTRING"
  (interactive)
  (setq ThirdVar-p (not ThirdVar-p)))
```

Now I want to add a new feature to the functions. I want them to display a message like:

```
The value of VAR is setted to VALUE
```

I tried with:

```el
(defun message-variable-t-nil-value (VAR) 
  (let* ((VAR_NAME (symbol-name VAR))
         (MESSAGE (concat "The value of " 
              VAR_NAME 
              " is setted to " 
              ;; ??? VALUE as a string ??? 
                          )))
    
    
         (if 'VAR (message (propertize MESSAGE
                                       'face '(:foreground "GreenYellow")))

           ;; *ELSE*
           (message (propertize MESSAGE
                                'face '(:foreground "OrangeRed"))))
         ))
```

The idea is to use it like:

```el
(message-variable-t-nil-value FirstVar-p)
```

in the funcions. Eg.:

```el
(defun toggle-first-var ()
  "DOCSTRING"
  (interactive)
  (setq FirstVar-p (not FirstVar-p))
  (message-variable-t-nil-value FirstVar))
```

Is there a built-in function to do it. How can I fix my function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the function you're looking for is [`format`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Formatting-Strings.html):

```lisp
(defun message-variable-t-nil-value (var) 
  (let* ((val  (and (boundp var)  (symbol-value var)))
         (msg  (format "The value of `%S' is now %S" var val)))
    (message (propertize msg 'face `(:foreground ,(if val
                                                      "GreenYellow"
                                                    "OrangeRed"))))))
```

The other functions you were looking for are `boundp` and `symbol-value`.

It does no good to test `'val` for non-`nil`: it's only nil if `val` is `nil`.  (Was that what you wanted?  I'm assuming instead that you wanted to check whether the symbol is bound as a variable.)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`format`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Formatting-Strings.html). It's the Lisp equivalent of C's `printf`. Unlike Common Lisp, Emacs Lisp's format specifications are similar to C's, with `%` as the special character.

```
(defun show-value-of-variable (symbol)
  (message (format "The value of %s is %S" symbol (symbol-value symbol))))
```

`%s` prints a somewhat human-friendly string, for example without quotes around a string. `%S` prints a string that can be read back to the same value (except for types that don't have a read syntax).

Comment: Your functions works but the Drew's one includes the color stuff. Thanks.